# How do I convert plain text links/URL's to HTML (images AND links)

Tags: php, html, regex

So I have a large string of text that can contain links to websites or images. I want to convert these plain URL's to html elements.

Example input:

```
Hi my name is Harry you can find my website here: http://www.harry-rox.com. Oh and what do you think of my my wife: http://www.anothersite.com/wife.jpg?
```

Needed output:

```
Hi my name is Harry you can find my website here: <a href="http://www.harry-rox.com">http://www.harry-rox.com</a>. Oh and what do you think of my my wife: <img src="http://www.anothersite.com/wife.jpg" />?
```

Note;

I found some regex examples that do one of both conversions (URL to href element, or image URL to  tag, but I can't seem to find way to combine them! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accomplish this in the following way ...

```
$str = 'Hi my name is Harry you can find my website here: http://www.harry-rox.com. Oh and what do you think of my my wife: http://www.anothersite.com/wife.jpg?';
$r1 = '/(http:\/\/[\S]+(?:jpg|jpeg|png|gif))/';
$r2 = '/(?<!src=")(http:\/\/[\S]+\b)/';
$sub1 = '<img src="$1"/>';
$sub2 = '<a href="$1">$1</a>';
$res = preg_replace($r1, $sub1, $str);
$result = preg_replace($r2, $sub2, $res);
echo $result;
```

**[DEMO](https://ideone.com/VDKypJ)**

Answer (score 0):

Use preg_replace [sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2daccbcc35cd498608be33260a0b704a8ccf03f8)

```
$count = null;
$string = "Hi my name is Harry you can find my website here: http://www.harry-rox.com. Oh and what do you think of my my wife: http://www.anothersite.com/wife.jpg?";
$string = preg_replace('~https?://(?![^" ]*(?:jpg|png|gif))[^" ]+\w~', '<a href="$0" target="_blank" title="$0">$0</a>', 'Hi my name is Harry you can find my website here: http://www.harry-rox.com. Oh and what do you think of my my wife: http://www.anothersite.com/wife.jpg?', -1, $count);
$string = preg_replace('~([a-z\\-_0-9\\/\\:\\.]*\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)).~', '<img src="$0" />', $string, -1, $count);
print $string;
```

Comment: This converts all URL's to links (href), but not the image link to an <img> tag.